# /dev/random EXTREMELY slow in Ubuntu for Windows 10 (WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, random

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 for Windows 10 (WSL2) on a Haswell laptop and I am getting about 0.6 bytes per second. As in 6 bytes total after 10 seconds of waiting. This is unacceptable. What is the problem?

**EDIT:** This only appears to be an issue when operating in WSL2 mode.
WSL1 = 40MiB/s
WSL2 = 0.6 byte/s

Comment: Why are you using `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: @terdon Because /dev/urandom is a CSPRNG that is seeded by an entropy pool while /dev/random supplies pure entropy. For my purposes a PRNG, even a cryptographically secure one, is not sufficient. Besides, why I do the things I do is not important. The only thing that is important is that /dev/random being *this* slow on any sort of modern device is clearly a bug or oversight of some kind.

Comment: @Lizardx First of all, WSL1 is the one that uses a emulation layer on top of the NT kernel. WSL2 uses a virtualized Linux kernel. So maybe check your facts. Secondly, I don't think your "Micro$oft sux" comment is remotely helpful or appropriate for stack exchange.

Comment: https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/not-enough-entropy/ https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-more-entropy-to-improve-cryptographic-randomness-on-linux/

Comment: @Chris_f however much I dislike Lizardx's tone he does still have a solid point; WSL2 does use a Linux kernel but it uses one built, configured and "tuned" by Microsoft inside a VM managed by Windows.  So you will still find issues peculiar to WSL... I suspect Microsoft isolated this in a VM which reduces its sources of entropy.  I wonder if [this might help](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/69433/10066).  You could get random data from windows to inject into WSL.

Comment: It also may be worth pointing out that you can seed the entropy pool yourself, and increase the entropy count: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html. Please note that this is also a **terrible** idea that will most likely end in fire.

Comment: Do not use /dev/random — is it *not* more secure and does not supply “pure entropy” [Reference](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)

Comment: Your CPU has a hardware true-RNG built-in (`rdrand` was new in IvyBridge, the generation before Haswell).  Apparently Linux isn't using that by default, but you can probably config that, or use a user-space daemon to feed rdrand into the kernel's entropy pool ([Add a file as entropy source for /dev/random](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/69433)).  Or use `rdrand` directly for you use-case if you trust Intel's CPU design.

Comment: @PeterCordes It does use it, but only to seed the SHA-1 IV (which is silly IMHO) at the moment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` in Linux are cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generators.  In older versions of the Linux kernel, `/dev/random` would block once initialized until additional sufficient entropy was accumulated, whereas `/dev/urandom` would not.  Since WSL2 is a virtual machine with a real Linux kernel, it has a limited set of entropy sources from which it can draw entropy and must rely on the host system for most of its entropy.  However, as long as it has received enough entropy when it boots, it's secure to use the CSPRNGs.

It sounds like in your environment, the CSPRNG has been seeded at boot from Windows, but isn't reseeded at a high rate.  That's fine, but it will cause `/dev/random` to block more frequently than you want.  Ultimately, this is a problem with the configuration of WSL2.

WSL1 probably doesn't have this problem because in such a case, `/dev/random` probably doesn't block and just uses the system CSPRNG, like `/dev/urandom`.  In [more recent versions of Linux](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/), the only time that `/dev/random` blocks is if enough entropy hasn't been accumulated at boot to seed the CSPRNG once; otherwise, it is completely equivalent to `/dev/urandom`.  This decision was made because there is no reasonable security difference in the two interfaces provided the pool has been appropriately initialized.

Since there's no measurable difference in these cases, if `/dev/random` is blocking and is too slow for you, the proper thing to do is use `/dev/urandom`, since they are the output of the same CSPRNG (which is based on ChaCha20).  The upstream Linux behavior will likely be the default in a future version of WSL2 anyway, since Microsoft will eventually incorporate a newer version of Linux.

Comment: *"This decision was made because there is no reasonable security difference in the two interfaces provided the pool has been appropriately initialized."* I think this might be a fallacy. It would make a huge difference if the seed (secrets) get leaked somehow, right? (Maybe via something Spectre-like?) That "drains" entropy.

Comment: Both are CSPRNGs and both are reseeded with entropy at the same rate.  Even if the state were compromised, it's evident that on your system after 30 seconds, there'd be 128 bits of entropy or more in the pool, which is sufficient and the pool would be reseeded.  Cryptographers recommend `/dev/urandom` or `getrandom(2)` for all purposes, so there's no reason to use `/dev/random`.  Many non-Linux OSes have never even had a blocking `/dev/random`.

Comment: I get that they're seeded at the same rate, but what I'm saying is, if the secret is leaked at some point, then the traditional `/dev/random` should be more secure because.it would actually block and wait during those 30 seconds for new entropy to be gathered, instead of relying mostly on the old one like `/dev/urandom` does. (I get that some kernels don't have `/dev/random` block, but that's beside my point. I'm talking about the blocking version.)

Comment: To my understanding, cryptographers recommend the non-blocking versions because (a) they examine the computational security assuming the secret doesn't leak, and (b) they don't want poor UX to lead to poorer security. Both of which are valid and I agree with them—I am *not* saying you should use `/dev/random` per se; most use cases should probably use `/dev/urandom` due to those reasons. I'm just saying these are *different* from claiming that there's no security difference between the two. It seems to me the difference is there; it's just not worth the trade-offs in typical applications.

Comment: If it's releasing 6 bytes every 10 seconds, then it's not securely reseeding, because 48 bits of entropy is eminently guessable, so exposing the output 6 bytes of entropy after a compromise is insecure and you're no better off.  Regardless, you did ask why this behavior occurred and why this difference between WSL1 and WSL2, so I think I've answered the question as asked.

Comment: @user541686: What I don't get is why `/dev/random` doesn't fallback to mixing the CPU hardware RNG that's present on all modern CPUs now. It's not fast but it's far better than blocking.

Comment: @Joshua: I think it's because they don't trust the CPU RNG enough to put all their eggs in that basket.

Comment: @user541686 *if the secret is leaked at some point ...*  Any attacker that can get the bits that seeded `/dev/urandom` can already get all your data too.  "If they break into my safe, they can get the combination to open it and read everything I have stored there."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's... so false. I even gave a counterexample (Spectre) right there in my first comment. So I visit a website, it manages to leak some bits of my memory with Spectre/MDS/etc. before I leave the site. It just so happens that those bits contain the OS RNG seed. You're claiming that fact implies the attacker now has access a TB of data on my disk, too? What?

Comment: @user541686: back to your initial claim: if the pool entropy leaked via Spectre, `/dev/random` doesn't know that and still thinks it has entropy in the pool, so the initial N bytes of output will be based on secrets already stolen by the attacker.  You're right that waiting for more true entropy could help in a use-case that reads *lots* of random data, not just one small read to medium read to seed its own CSPRNG, against an attacker that can't keep peeking into the entropy pool fast / accurately enough to keep up (or in the window between it being available and read.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: It doesn't have to be a "lot" though. Let's say N = 32 here to have a concrete example. With `/dev/random`, that would compromise the AES-256 key of your connection to the next server you connect to. But not the servers after that, because the kernel would block until it has new entropy.  Whereas with `/dev/urandom`, the kernel would never block, so even with N = 32, who knows how many of your subsequent connections will have leaked keys.

Comment: @user541686: yes, that's true on an entropy-starved machine like this that doesn't use anything to feed HW RNG into the pool to refill it, and doesn't have other good sources of entropy.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Depends how fast you're connecting to other servers and how fast you're replenishing the entropy. For a user visiting websites, it probably won't leak anything outside that website (though hopefully connections to 3rd-party domains during that visit won't get compromised). For a network-intensive server, I'm not so sure; it might come down to whether they trust their hardware RNGs. But again, I'm not saying this matters for the average user or the average application. Most applications should use `/dev/urandom` as we all agree.

Comment: @user541686 Soooo attack vectors like Spectre can only read the bits used to seed `/dev/urandom`?  If someone can use something like Spectre to read the bits used to seed `/dev/urandom`, **they're not going to bother doing that, they're going to read what's important**.  Again, you're all worried about the combination to the safe while the thieves who have already opened the safe are walking off with the gold bars you used to have stored in that safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Uhm, I don't think you're quite understanding what I'm saying, but okay.

Comment: @user541686 ***YOU*** invoked [Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/): "Meltdown and Spectre exploit critical vulnerabilities in modern processors. These hardware vulnerabilities allow programs to steal data which is currently processed on the computer. While programs are typically not permitted to read data from other programs, a malicious program can exploit Meltdown and Spectre to get hold of secrets stored in the memory of other running programs."  If someone can do that, they're not going to bother reading the bits used to seed `/dev/urandom`, ***they'll just read your secret data***.

Comment: (cont)  The fact that you used `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` or even `/dev/rectalDB` for your random bits won't matter at all in that case.  You're worried about protecting the wrong thing if something like Spectre is a real threat.  You're obsessing over the combination to a safe that's already been blown wide open in that case.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: You keep repeating yourself while sounding angrier. Just relax. Maybe I'm wrong. It's OK.

Comment: @user541686 As they shouldn't. There was a chip that returned all zeroes from rdrand/rdseed. And there are many chips whose rdrand/rdseed data can be leaked by Spectre.

Comment: (I don't mean the OS entropy pool, I mean the output from random instructions *themselves* could be leaked, directly, via a CPU bug. From any core on the same chip.)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested this out in WSL2 Ubuntu myself, but I ran into a similar issue on a CentOS 6 VM a while back. Installing and running the `haveged` service fixed my problem with a slow /dev/random.  Might be worth a try.

> Linux  pools  randomness  for  distribution  by  the  /dev/random  and /dev/urandom device interfaces. The standard mechanisms of filling the /dev/random pool may not be  sufficient to  meet  demand  on  systems  with  high  needs  or  limited  user  interaction. In those circumstances, haveged may be run as a privileged daemon  to  fill  the  /dev/random  pool whenever  the  supply  of random bits in /dev/random falls below the low water mark of the device.
>
> https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/haveged.8.html

Otherwise, like @bk2204 said, /dev/urandom may be your best alternative.